# Azure Notification Hub - Invalid authorization token signature with Java

Tags: java, azure, push-notification, token, azure-notificationhub

Hi all I'm trying to send a notification with Azure Notification Hub in Java.

This is the code I used:

```
     NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub("Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXXXXX;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "myHubName");                                                 
     String message = "{\"data\":{\"msg\":\"Hello from Java!\"}}";
     Notification n = Notification.createGcmNotification(message);
     NotificationOutcome result = hub.sendNotification(n);
     return result.getNotificationId();
```

The problem is that I get an **Invalid authorization token signature** error when I try to get the NotificationOutcome object.

I assume that the problem is in the generation of the token, which is generated with the following method of **NotificationHub** class:

```
private String generateSasToken(URI uri) {
    String targetUri;
    try {
        targetUri = URLEncoder
                .encode(uri.toString().toLowerCase(), "UTF-8")
                .toLowerCase();

        long expiresOnDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        expiresOnDate += SdkGlobalSettings.getAuthorizationTokenExpirationInMinutes() * 60 * 1000;
        long expires = expiresOnDate / 1000;
        String toSign = targetUri + "\n" + expires;



        // Get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
        byte[] keyBytes = SasKeyValue.getBytes("UTF-8");
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");

        // Get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(signingKey);

        // Compute the hmac on input data bytes
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // Convert raw bytes to Hex
        String signature = URLEncoder.encode(
                Base64.encodeBase64String(rawHmac), "UTF-8");//

        // construct authorization string
        String token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + targetUri + "&sig="
                + signature + "&se=" + expires + "&skn=" + SasKeyName;
        System.out.println(token);
        return token;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I tried the same example using php and it worked. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.